# groupby apply not giving expected result

Tags: python, pandas, apply, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python, and I am trying to find the std of a circular data (wind directions) grouping the data by some characteristics.
Here is a set of the df I am using.

```
  Profile   bin     inflow_direction
0   1        51     331.7
1   1        51     332.8
2   1        51     334.1
3   1        51     335.4
4   1        51     336.4
5   1        66     337.3
6   1        66     337.5
7   1        66     337.6
8   1        66     337.7
9   1        66     337.6
```

I need the std for every group of bin inside each Profile.
I have defined the std function as:

`def circstd(j) :
    samples = np.radians (j)
    return scipy.stats.circstd(samples, high=6.283185307179586, low=0, axis=None)`

when I group:

```
df.groupby(['Profile','bin']).apply(circstd)
```

The out is:

```
idscng_f  bin
 1         51     0.567811

           66     0.671470
```

But I was expecting

```
idscng_f  bin
 1         51     0.0296

           66     0.0025
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: try specifying the column on which the action is to be performed? + The conversion to radians on the same step complicates things. Split those two things up, get it to work, understand it and then merge them back together if you want to

Comment: How can I specify - using the group by - the column on which the action is to be performed?

Comment: see method 1 on the answer by @Nickil Maveli below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) after converting angles from degrees to radians:

```
def simple_circstd(j) :
    return np.std(np.radians(j))['inflow_direction']
```

Perform `Groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['Profile','bin']).apply(simple_circtd)
```

Resulting output obtained:

```
Profile  bin
1        51     0.029650
         66     0.002367
dtype: float64
```

Comment: You mean the precision. It loses precision mostly after 3/4 decimal digits.

Comment: The result for the Method 1 is giving me different result. 
             idscng_f  bin
               1         51     1.490116e-08
              66     2.367480e-03
              dtype: float64
The second method gives me the result needed, but I wonder if it will work for other angles, since it is circular data.

Comment: Oh, the reason I included `np.nonzero` was because I was getting zero values for other elements and just 1 finite value for the dummy data you provided. Must be not the case with the real one. I'll delete it if it's giving you incorrect results. And yes, the second approach would work as it basically converts from deg to rad and computes `std` on the circular array.

Comment: Ok! Problem solved using arr[2] as return! For some reason the std was not returning zero for the column with the bin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `SeriesGroupBy` object to use `apply()` on.

`df.groupby(['Profile','bin'])["inflow_direction"].apply(circstd)` 
will do the work.

output:

```
Profile  bin
1        51     0.029650
         66     0.002367
Name: inflow_direction, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice! This too gives the right result. Never struck my mind before.